# Removing trailing slash by htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, trailing-slash, duplicate-content

Depending on google suggestions, I tried to add some codes to my .htaccess to prevent duplicate content.
This is my code:

```
#Duplicate Content
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.soomar63.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.soomar63.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.soomar63.com/ [R=301,L]
#Remove Trailing Slash
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?soomar63\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !administrator/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://www.soomar63.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This code is working fine, it have just a little problem:

This code corrects following links:

```
soomar63.com -> www.soomar63.com
soomar63.com/ -> www.soomar63.com
soomar63.com/index.php/ -> www.soomar63.com
soomar63.com/about.html/ -> www.soomar63.com/about.html
```

But it dosen't corrects following links:

```
soomar63.com/index.php?mylink/ -> must correct to www.soomar63.com/index.php?mylink
soomar63.com/about.html#mylink/ -> must correct to www.soomar63.com/about.html#mylink
```

Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `#Remove Trailing Slash` rules with below

```
#Remove Trailing Slash

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?soomar63\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^/?administrator$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.soomar63.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay, but it didn't solve my problem, this code creates infinite loop in my site and give the error page...